# VBA to query field contents in CSV

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, adodb

I'm struggling with ADO connections/recordsets.

My problem statement is: a function that will return the first value of a chosen field, in a chosen .csv file.

I am doing this to identify variably-named .csv files before adding the data to the relevant tables in a database. I am making the assumption that this field is always present and that either it is consistent throughout the file, or only relevant ones are grouped (this is controlled higher up the chain and is certain enough).

My code is being run as part of a module in an MS Access database:

```
Public Function GetFirstItem(File As Scripting.File, Field As String)
    
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, Recordset As ADODB.Recordset, SQL As String
    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 / Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=""" & File.ParentFolder & _
        """; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"
    
    SQL = "SELECT " & Field & " FROM """ & File.Name & """ LIMIT 1"
    
    Debug.Print Conn.ConnectionString
    Debug.Print SQL
    
    Conn.Open
    
    Recordset.Source = SQL
    Recordset.ActiveConnection = Conn.ConnectionString
    
    Recordset.Open
    Recordset.MoveFirst
    
    'GetFirstItem = Recordset!Questionnaire
    
    Recordset.Close
    Conn.Close
    Set Recordset = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Function
```

ConnectionString = `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source="D:\Documents\Jobs\TestPath"; Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;";`

Field = `Questionnaire`

SQL = `SELECT Questionnaire FROM "test.csv" LIMIT 1`

I get an error on `Recordset.Open` of:

[image: VBA error msg]

This may be (is probably) down to a complete lack of understanding of how ADO connections/recordsets work. I have tried sans-quotes and it complains about a malformed `FROM` expression. Additionally, once this hurdle is overcome I am unsure of the syntax of how to return the result of my query. If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears!

Thanks.

Comment: You can try defining a full path instead of only the file name. E.g., "C:\Temp\test.csv"

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access you don't need ADO library to query a CSV file:

```
Public Function GetFirstItem(File As Scripting.File, Field As String) As String
    
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, SQL As String
    
    SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 [" & Field & "]" _
    & " FROM [" & File.Name & "]" _
    & " IN '" & File.ParentFolder & "'[Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes];"
    
    Debug.Print SQL
    
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    GetFirstItem = RS(0)
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Usage:

```
?GetFirstItem(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").getfile("c:\path\to\your\file.csv"), "your field")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten to define the return type and use Access SQL syntax — oops!

Cheers for pointing out I don't need to use the ADO library. This will certainly be what I end up doing (it's much simpler/neater), but is there any reason why using ADO shouldn't work? I'm still quite curious about what is wrong with my example connection above that it can't find the file.

Comment: @BlankedyBlank the problem may be in double quotes or in the absence of square brackets but i'm not sure.

Comment: I did try some variations of single quotes/square brackets, but perhaps not the right ones and both at the same time. I suppose it will have to remain a mystery. I have accepted your solution and rewritten that part of my program, thank you.